# Deleting rows of a matrix in which specific columns match a condition

Tags: matrix, data

Say that I have the following table:

```
{{4.95455, 10.8, 0., 0.02}, {3.43939, 7.46667, 0., 0.03}, {2.68182,5.8, 0., 0.04}, 
{2.22727, 4.8, 0., 0.05},{0.3,08,0.1,0.2},{0.5,1,0.2,0.4},{0.564555, -10.3617, 0.99, 0.94}}
```

Now I want to remove every row in which: a) the first two elements of each row are above 1, and b) the second element of each row is lower than the first element of each row. I tried to search for a solution but the ones that I find are always about lists and/or removing elements that match particular values (and not conditions). Following these conditions, I would get:

```
{{0.3,08,0.1,0.2},{0.5,1,0.2,0.4}}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Select[Min[#[[;; 2]]] <= 1 && #[[2]] >= #[[1]] &]@list
```

> ```
>  {{0.3, 8, 0.1, 0.2}, {0.5, 1, 0.2, 0.4}}
> ```

Also:

```
Select[#[[1]] <= Min[1, #[[2]]] &] @ list
```

> ```
> {{0.3, 8, 0.1, 0.2}, {0.5, 1, 0.2, 0.4}}
> ```

```
Cases[{a_, b_, ___} /; a <= Min[1, b]] @ list
```

> ```
> {{0.3, 8, 0.1, 0.2}, {0.5, 1, 0.2, 0.4}}
> ```

```
DeleteCases[{a_, b_, __} /; Min[{a, b}] > 1 || b < a]@list
```

> ```
>  {{0.3, 8, 0.1, 0.2}, {0.5, 1, 0.2, 0.4}}
> ```